# How can I do effect like this(see inside) by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blur

I have the answer now. Please vote down to close this question. Thank you very much.

It's like when you clicked Clear browsing data in Google Chrome settings. The behind screen is blur and then Clear browsing data window comes up. You can't go back to settings which is blur now unless you closed the Clear browsing data. I don't know what this effect is called or how can do that.

[image]

Please advise or give the reference(s).

Thank you.

Comment: It's called a modal dialog.

Comment: It's called a "modal dialogue". If you use jQuery, you can use the jQuery UI Dialog widget.

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't think that's the effect he's talking about.

Comment: @Barmar I realized it's not.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to achieve that is by using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: modal ? try with this tutorial : http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Comment: The screen is not blurred (at least not in Chrome 24). There is a translucent overlay atop everything but the modal.

Comment: It is non-constructive to ask for people to close the question once you have got the answer. You should instead improve the question so that it presents the problem, in a manner that helps future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css3 filters if the browser supports it:

```
div {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

For the dialog look for "modal dialogs". Then you can switch the css with a class depending if the dialog is open or closed.

**Blur demo:** http://jsbin.com/atisiz/1/edit

Comment: It think the question is about how to achieve a modal dialog with a semi-transparent overlay.

Comment: I didn't see anything about semi-transparent. I understand the question is about how to create a dialog and blur the background.

Comment: He says "blur", but what chrome does is a white overlay with the opacity tweaked. In any case, I voted to close the question, it's too broad.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yeah I read "blur" and my eyes saw blur, but I realize now it's just an overlay.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please vote to close this question. I have my answer now.

Comment: If this helps consider just accepting this answer. You need 4 more votes to close the question.